# The font (Arial) is not applied to the body of my mail when using Apple Mail on MacOS

Tags: mail.app, font

I work with colleagues who use Windows and I have noticed that my font is not applied to the text when I select Arial. This results in the text being displayed in Times New Roman (the default font on Windows), which is very annoying!

I checked the html code sent on a web based html client, and noticed that there are no `<font face="Font Name"></font>` statements in the portions of text for which I selected Arial, but there are for any other font:

```
<div _ngcontent-ycs-c416="" class="mailContent-open-body">
   <div class="ws-ng-mail-style--225eJzz9HPyjwAABGYBgQ">
      Hello,
      <div><br></div>
      <div>This is a test:</div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div>Arial</div>
      <div><font face="Arial Black"><span style="font-style:normal;"><b>Arial Black</b></span></font></div>
      <div><b><font face="Arial Narrow">Arial Narrow</font></b></div>
      <div><font><font face="Arial Rounded MT Bold"><span style="font-style:normal;">Arial Rounded MT Bold</span></font></font></div>
      <div><font><font face="Arial Unicode MS"><span style="font-style:normal;">Arial Unicode MS</span></font></font></div>
      <div><font>Arial</font></div>
      <div><font><font face="Arial Unicode MS"><br></font></font>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But when I select another font, like "Helvetica", "Times New Roman", "Verdana", the `<font face="Font Name"></font>` statement is added to the html code.
I even tried with "Arial Black", "Arial Narrow", "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Arial Unicode MS", and it works. So the only font that has this issue is "Arial" apparently!

My configuration: macOS Ventura 13.1 / Mail 16.0 (3731.300.101.1.3)

Comment: If you are selecting Arial in the Mail New Message pane, try making sure that you have a different font selected in Mail > Preferences > Fonts > Message Font.

Comment: @TomGewecke, yes I noticed that after posting this message. It's crazy because this setting also changes the default font of the email body. This means that to avoid this problem, we have to manually change the font every time we write a new email. This is unbelievable!

Comment: It's been like that forever.  People who want rational behavior regarding default fonts often switch to Outlook.